# How to format sequence of strings into some predetermined length with fasta like header with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, bioinformatics

I have a text file called `input.txt` that looks like this.

```
A C H E C Q D S S C H H C R Q K L E D T S C H L E D V G K M
N T Y H C G E G I N N G P N A S C K F M L P C V V A E F E N H T
E T D W R C K L E A E H C D C K D A A V N H H F Y S L C K D V T E E W
```

Note that the input above has 3 rows of amino acid sequences.

I have a text file called input.txt that looks like this.

```
A C H E C Q D S S C H H C R Q K L E D T S C H L E D V G K M
N T Y H C G E G I N N G P N A S C K F M L P C V V A E F E N H T
E T D W R C K L E A E H C D C K D A A V N H H F Y S L C K D V T E E W
```

Note that the input above has 3 rows of amino acid sequences.

I'd like to convert that into the format below.

```
<|endoftext|>
ACHECQDSSCHHCRQKLEDTSCHLEDVGKM
<|endoftext|>
NTYHCGEGINNGPNASCKFMLPCVVAEFEN
HT
<|endoftext|>
ETDWRCKLEAEHCDCKDAAVNHHFYSLCKD
VTEEW
```

Every beginning of the amino acid sequence should begin with this string "<|endoftext|>"
and each new line should be no more than 30 amino acids.

I have this code, but it doesn't do the job:

```
def process_amino_acids(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r") as file:
        data = file.read().replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "")

    output = "<|endoftext|>"
    for i, amino_acid in enumerate(data):
        if i % 30 == 0 and i != 0:
            output += "\n"
        output += amino_acid
    return output


def main():
    input_file = "data/input.txt"
    processed_amino_acids = process_amino_acids(input_file)

    with open("data/output.txt", "w") as output_file:
        output_file.write(processed_amino_acids)

    print("Formatted amino acid sequences are written to output.txt")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output it gave is this:

```
<|endoftext|>ACHECQDSSCHHCRQKLEDTSCHLEDVGKM
NTYHCGEGINNGPNASCKFMLPCVVAEFEN
HTETDWRCKLEAEHCDCKDAAVNHHFYSLC
KDVTEEW
```

How can I do it properly with Python?

Comment: Neither of these format is fasta, BTW. Not sure if this matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python comes with batteries included, use [`textwrap.wrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html):

```
from textwrap import wrap

with (open('input.txt') as f,
      open('output.txt', 'w') as out
     ):
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace(' ', '')
        out.write('<|endoftext|>\n')
        out.write('\n'.join(wrap(line, width=30)))
        out.write('\n')
```

Output file:

```
<|endoftext|>
ACHECQDSSCHHCRQKLEDTSCHLEDVGKM
<|endoftext|>
NTYHCGEGINNGPNASCKFMLPCVVAEFEN
HT
<|endoftext|>
ETDWRCKLEAEHCDCKDAAVNHHFYSLCKD
VTEEW
```